# Obtener números y medida de un dataframe con Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe con especies de tiburones, en la misma columna tengo el nombre de le especie y su tamaño, lo que quiero es obtener una columna sólo con el tamaño y su medida, es decir en metros o pies según corresponda. y luego pasar todas las medidas a metros.

**Species**:

> 2 m shark
>   Tiger shark, 10?
>   White shark
>   Bull shark, 6'
>   Bull shark, 3.5 m
>   3' to 4' shark
>   5' shark
>   Bull shark, 4' to 5'
>   Mako shark, 1.5 m [5']
>   Bull sharks x 2
>   Shark involvement not confirmed
>   0.9 m  to 1.2 m [3' to 4'] shark
>   0.9 m to 1.2 m [3' to 4'] white shark
>   0.7 m [2.5'] sand shark
>   1.2 m to 1.5 m [4' to 5'] shark
>   "A small shark"
>   "small shark"
>   a small shark
>   Shark involvement prior to death not confirmed
>   Tiger shark, 1.8 m [6']
>   Possibly a juvenile blacktip or spinner shark

Con esto consigo sacar los números pero lo que quiero es obtenerlos con la `m` (metro) o la  `'` (pies):

```
    df['titles5'] = df['aa'].str.extract('([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)', expand=True) # saca los numeros 
    df
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener cuando en una línea hay varias opciones? E.g., `1.2 m to 1.5 m [4' to 5'] shark`

Comment: me gustaria poder obtener los 2 valores que hay y hacer despues la media, pero usando la formula que he puesto solo me saca el primer numero,

Comment: A veces hay metros y a veces hay pies, son 4 números. Quizá es mejor meter algo de lógica con las funciones para cadenas en lugar de usar una regex. Sin duda será más lento pero más legible.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
import re

lista = [
  "2 m shark",
  "Tiger shark, 10?",
  "White shark",
  "Bull shark, 6'",
  "Bull shark, 3.5 m",
  "3' to 4' shark",
  "5' shark",
  "Bull shark, 4' to 5'",
  "Mako shark, 1.5 m [5']",
  "Bull sharks x 2",
  "Shark involvement not confirmed",
  "0.9 m to 1.2 m [3' to 4'] shark",
  "0.9 m to 1.2 m [3' to 4'] white shark",
  "0.7 m [2.5'] sand shark",
  "1.2 m to 1.5 m [4' to 5'] shark",
  "A small shark",
  "small shark",
  "a small shark",
  "Shark involvement prior to death not confirmed",
  "Tiger shark, 1.8 m [6']",
  "Possibly a juvenile blacktip or spinner shark"
]

for v in lista:
  print("{0} --> {1}".format(v,re.findall('\d+\.?\d{0,2} m|\d+\.?\d{0,2}\'', v)))
```

Con esto obtienes:

```
2 m shark --> ['2 m']
Tiger shark, 10? --> []
White shark --> []
Bull shark, 6' --> ["6'"]
Bull shark, 3.5 m --> ['3.5 m']
3' to 4' shark --> ["3'", "4'"]
5' shark --> ["5'"]
Bull shark, 4' to 5' --> ["4'", "5'"]
Mako shark, 1.5 m [5'] --> ['1.5 m', "5'"]
Bull sharks x 2 --> []
Shark involvement not confirmed --> []
0.9 m to 1.2 m [3' to 4'] shark --> ['0.9 m', '1.2 m', "3'", "4'"]
0.9 m to 1.2 m [3' to 4'] white shark --> ['0.9 m', '1.2 m', "3'", "4'"]
0.7 m [2.5'] sand shark --> ['0.7 m', "2.5'"]
1.2 m to 1.5 m [4' to 5'] shark --> ['1.2 m', '1.5 m', "4'", "5'"]
A small shark --> []
small shark --> []
a small shark --> []
Shark involvement prior to death not confirmed --> []
Tiger shark, 1.8 m [6'] --> ['1.8 m', "6'"]
Possibly a juvenile blacktip or spinner shark --> []
```

Resumiendo, obtenemos:

- Un valor en metros (`<n>` m)
- Un valor en pies (`<n>`')
- rangos en metros (`<n>` m,  m)
- rangos en pies (`<n>`', `<n>`')

El resto es "basura" que no podremos procesar, con los valores entiendo que es relativamente simple llevarlo a un dato numérico.

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Al final creo que la he liado demasiado pero he conseguido sacar lo que quería aunque de una forma un poco más tosca, porque queria conservar el dataframe.

```
df['metross'] = df['aa'].str.extract("(\d*\.\d+ m to \d*\.\d+ )", expand=True) # con esto saco los numeros asi 3 m to 4
df['m1'] = df['metross'].str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", expand=True) # saca primer numero
df['m2'] = df['metross'].str.extract("( \d*\.\d+)", expand=True) # saca segundo numero 
df['media_metros'] = (df['m1'].astype(float)+df['m2'].astype(float))/2 # calcula la media entre los 2

# para eliminar las columnas no utiles
df.pop('m1') 
df.pop('m2')
df.pop('metross')

# saca los tamaños en pies
df['pies'] = df['aa'].str.extract("(\d+' to \d+')", expand=True) # 3' to 4'
df['pies1'] = df['pies'].str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", expand=True) #saca el primer numero
df['pies2'] = df['pies'].str.extract("( \d+)", expand=True) # saca el segundo numero 

df.pop('pies')

df['media_pies'] = (df['pies1'].astype(float)+df['pies2'].astype(float))/2 # calcula la media entre los 2
df['media_pies']  = (df['media_pies'].astype(float)*0.3048).round(2) # pasa los pies a metros

df.pop('pies1')
df.pop('pies2')

df['size1'] = df['media_metros'].combine_first(df['media_pies']) # combino en una columna las dos medias, cogiendo como preferencia la columna metros

df.pop('media_metros')
df.pop('media_pies')
df # con esto saco una columna con la media de los tamaños, tomando como preferencia los metros
```

Ahora saco los tamaños en otras dos columnas diferentes separando metros y pies

```
df['pies'] = df['aa'].str.extract("(\d*\.\d+'|\d+')", expand=True) # saca tamaño en pies 6'
df['metros'] = df['aa'].str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+ m)", expand=True) # saca tamaño en metros 2 m
df['metros2'] = df['metros'].str.extract("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", expand=True) # saca sólo los numeros en metros
df['pies2'] = df['pies'].str.extract("(\d*\.\d+|\d+)", expand=True) # saca sólo los numeros en pies
#elimino columnas que ya no use
df.pop('pies')
df.pop('metros')

df['pies2']  = (df['pies2'].astype(float)*0.3048).round(2) # paso los pies a metros

#combino las columnas 
df['sizeee'] = df['size1'].combine_first(df['metros2']) #combina columnas cogiendo size1 como preferente
df['size'] = df['sizeee'].combine_first(df['pies2'])
#elimino todas las columnas que ya no use
df.pop('metros2')
df.pop('size1')
df.pop('sizeee')
df.pop('pies2')
df
```